# How do I create custom cells in SwiftUI ? where each cell color is from an specific hex number list

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a .txt list where I get the hex values for the color of each cell in the List. How do I set the value for each cell?

I've tried to iterate inside the list with a ForEach loop but I don't really know how to use that loop.

This is the code that I needed in the UIKit version (fromHexToColor() is a UIColor extension):

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        let label: String = hexColorNames[indexPath.row]

        cell.cellLabel.text = label
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor().fromHexToUIColor(hexColorNames[indexPath.row])

        return cell

    }
```

I expect a whole array of cells inside the list where each cell background is from the hex value in the list.
[this is the UIKit version of the expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv040.png)

Comment: Instead of using UITableView use List control

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you going:

```
import SwiftUI

func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> Color {
    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    if ((cString.count) != 6) {
        return Color.gray
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt64 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)

    return Color(
        red: Double((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: Double((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: Double(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0
    )
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let colors: [String] = ["#d3d3d3", "#7f7f7f", "#000000", "#FFFFFF"]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                Text(color.description.capitalized)
                    .background(hexStringToUIColor(hex: color))
            }
        }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```